# A possible bug about WordCharacter on CJK characters

Tags: string-manipulation, documentation, unicode

According to the documentation of [`WordCharacter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCharacter.html):

> `WordCharacter` matches any character for which either `LetterQ` or `DigitQ` yields True.

However, the results of the following code seem not compatible with the doc:

```
StringMatchQ[#, WordCharacter] & /@ {"a", "1", ".", " ", "中", "あ"}
LetterQ[#] || DigitQ[#] & /@ {"a", "1", ".", " ", "中", "あ"}
```

> {True, True, False, False, **True**, **True**}
>
> {True, True, False, False, **False**, **False**}

I suppose there is a special rule to handle CJK characters, so it's the doc which should be corrected, am I right?

(As the motivation of this "discovery", I was trying to match any characters not belong to CJK.)

Comment: Your example does not violate what the documentation states, it's just that the reverse isn't true (it would seem): `WordCharacter` does not not match any character which neither `LetterQ` nor `DigitQ` matches.

Comment: @Pickett Your logic is right of course. But I can't agree with you, as it would make the doc sounding like playing with words...

Comment: The documentation is certainly wrong. `LetterQ` is only usable for the Latin and Greek alphabets, and even then only the letters that exist in English and modern Greek. `StringMatchQ` relies on the PCRE library, so it considers `WordCharacter` whatever PCRE does. This extends at least to some other alphabets/character types.

Comment: The result is difference with you [here](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/22/58d189a683b81.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! @yode I just tried and my 11.0 agrees with your result. I think [Alexey Popkov](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov)'s answer addressed the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the "[Implementation Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047)" section of the official tutorial "Working with String Patterns" we read:

> Because PCRE currently does not support preset character classes with characters beyond character code 255, the word and letter character classes (such as `WordCharacter` and `LetterCharacter`) only include character codes in the Unicode range 0–255. Thus `LetterCharacter` and `_?LetterQ` do not give equivalent results beyond character code 255.

The above-cited Documentation section wasn't updated [since](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/Programming/StringPatternsInMathematica/AdvancedDocumentationStringPatternsImplementationDetails.html) *Mathematica* version 5.2 ([July-2005](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html)), and shouldn't be correct anymore because starting from PCRE version 8.32 ([30-November-2012](http://pcre.org/original/changelog.txt)) the latter [supports](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) Unicode:

> PCRE_UCP
>
> This option changes the way PCRE processes \B, \b, \D, \d, \S, \s, 
>   \W, \w,  and  some  of  the POSIX character classes. By default, only
>   ASCII characters are recognized, but if PCRE_UCP is set,  Unicode 
>   properties are  used instead to classify characters. More details are
>   given in the section on generic character types in the pcrepattern
>   page. If you  set PCRE_UCP,  matching  one of the items it affects
>   takes much longer. The option is available only if PCRE has been
>   compiled with  Unicode  property support.
>
> <...>
>
> In UTF-8 (UTF-16, UTF-32) mode, characters with values greater than 255 (0xffff)  can be included in a class as a literal string of data units, or by using the \x{ escaping mechanism.

Starting from *Mathematica* version 10 the two lines of code in the question produce identical results but in general these tests are different, and (as of *Mathematica* version 11.1.0) the results aren't the same for 705 characters from the Unicode table as one can see from the following:

```
unicode = FromCharacterCode /@ Range[0, 65276];
test1 = StringMatchQ[#, WordCharacter] & /@ unicode;
test2 = LetterQ[#] || DigitQ[#] & /@ unicode;
Pick[unicode, MapThread[Unequal, {test1, test2}]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice finding! Thanks! So maybe I should stick with a self-maintained Unicode block table.

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty ugly hack, but maybe it will inspire you to something better.

```
leastCJK = ToCharacterCode["⺀"][[1]];
StringMatchQ[#, _?(ToCharacterCode[#][[1]] < leastCJK &)] & /@ 
  {"a", "1", ".", " ", "中", "あ"}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, False, False}
> ```

Note: "⺀" is unicode character U+2E80, CJK RADICAL REPEAT

This hack can be used with `Repeat` to ignore CJK strings

```
StringCases[
  "the quick fox...本当に日本語を勉強していますか...jumped", 
  Repeated[_?(ToCharacterCode[#][[1]] < leastCJK &)], 
  Overlaps -> False]
```

> ```
> {"the quick fox...", "...jumped"}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @m_goldberg ! This is how I'm dealing the problem right now. I hope there be a `CJKCharacter` :)

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg , I think [Alexey's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140658/17) gives very insightful information. If it's fine with you, I would like to accept it.

Comment: @Silvia. Please feel free to do so.