# What types of string patterns can't be translated into regexes and hence do not work?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, conversion, regular-expressions

In a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108481/can-mathematica-convert-a-regularexpression-into-a-stringexpression-or-vice-vers#comment339389_108481) to related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108481/280) [Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) made an interesting remark:

> ... because string patterns are converted into regular expressions and
>   matched using PCRE, they are subject to some strange and perhaps
>   unexpected limitations versus ordinary patterns. One can easily be
>   trapped by the generality of expression patterns and write a string
>   pattern that can't actually be expressed as a regular expression.

I think it would be very useful both from practical and educational points of view to have a list of *types* of string patterns which can't be converted into regular expressions. Periodically when I write a string pattern it doesn't work for unobvious reason and having a set of non-convertible constructs (especially with short explanations why conversion is impossible) would be very enlightening.

Comment: `Except["some text"]`. see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18193/5467) and your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Two examples are given under the "[Implementation Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047)" section of the official tutorial "Working with String Patterns" (thanks to [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) for the [pointer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/how-do-i-perform-string-matching-and-replacements#comment20112_6999)):

> Because PCRE currently does not support preset character classes with characters beyond character code 255, the word and letter character classes (such as `WordCharacter` and `LetterCharacter`) only include character codes in the Unicode range 0–255. Thus `LetterCharacter` and `_?LetterQ` do not give equivalent results beyond character code 255.
>
> Because of a similar PCRE restriction, case-insensitive matching (for example, with `IgnoreCase->True`) will only apply to letters in the Unicode range 0–127 (that is, the normal English letters "a"–"z" and "A"–"Z").

The above statements aren't completely correct because PCRE currently [supports Unicode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140658/280), and starting from *Mathematica* version 10 `WordCharacter` and `LetterCharacter` also support characters beyond character code 255. Unfortunately it is still not the case for the `IgnoreCase -> True` option.